# How to get the data of a post form with serializeArray?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send the data of a form and receive it using PHP to save it into database.
I am sending the data as below

```
    $http.post('/Marketing/Edit', {
            data: $("#edit").serializeArray()
    }).
```

and here is snippet of what I get is from "Developer Tools - Inspect Element" is

```
{data: [{name: "category", value: "none"},…]}
data: [{name: "category", value: "none"},…]
0: {name: "category", value: "none"}
name: "category"
value: "none"
```

I am trying to get them using `$_POST` but I feel this is not the correct way to do.

How to get the data?

**Update**

While trying to get the data with `$_POST` I get this:
`Undefined index: data`

Comment: Is that angularjs `$http`? If so default contentType is application/json and you either need to change contentType or use file_get_contents

Comment: It's quite correct to read from `$_POST` to get the POST data. Be aware of sanitizing your data and making sure that there is no SQL injection.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the correct way? This what the `$_POST`-super global is for.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh - Instead of sanitizing the data, you should use validation and prepared statements. It's better to store the data "as is" and encode it properly when it's used.

Comment: Or you can use some REST framework to get data on the PHP backend. In that case, you need to deserialize the JSON to the object.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh I made an update in my question I get  `Undefined index: data`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree, however I can't make it work. I have updated my question

Comment: Please show us your code as well, not just the error message. You should also do `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` and see what they contain.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I get this: `array (size=0)
  empty`

Comment: For which var_dump()? I suggested two different ones.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson for the first.
I have tried some things and I can echo this `[{"name":"category","value":"none"},` now

Comment: Then just use `json_decode()` on it and you should have an array with all the data: `$data = json_decode($theJsonString, true);`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am now printing this `0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'category' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'none' (length=4)` however I wanted the name and value to be the actual data instead